# Get Workspace source control folder in the workflow as an argument

Tags: workflow-activity

I am creating a custom activity for my build in TFS 2010, and I need to pass the activity the source control folder for the current build definition.

I need this as it is defined on the Workspace screen in the build definition screen, such as a string like "$/Project/Folder".

I can't find the appropriate property to pass as an argument to my activity.  I've found BuildDetail.TeamProject just returned "Project", but haven't had much success with anything else.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You would like to know how to pass into your activity an additional parameter, or how to retrieve some source control path(s) during build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property like

```
public InArgument<Workspace> CurrentWorkspace { get; set;}
```

In the overriden execute method you can access the workspace like

```
var workspace = context.GetValue<Workspace>(this.CurrentWorkspace);
foreach (var folder in workspace.Folders)
{
   //
}
```

To use the Workspace type you need an using to

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
```

For detailed information look at [Ewald Hofmans blog](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx)

Comment: excellent, with your suggestion I got it to work by using
Workspace.Folders()(0).DisplayServerItem